# Random array not giving desired result php (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have array with 2 indexes 0 and 1 i want when i call it should select random from these indexes 
my array is as

```
'schools' => [
    'records' => [
        'students' => [
            'add' => [
            'text 1',
            'text 2'
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

here my array is as

```
trans('app.schools.records.students.add')
```

Its now pick both text 1 and text 2 so i passed it 2 my method in helper as

```
{{gettitles(trans('app.schools.records.students.add'))}}
```

My get gettitles method looks as

```
function gettitles ($array){
  $rand_keys = array_rand($array, 2);
  echo $array[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
  echo $array[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
}
```

Its always pick up both if i echo index 0 its only ist text...
But i want only one randomly from both text 1 and text 2
Please Help to fix it 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($array, 2);
```

You're telling it to return 2 elements. The 2 is the number of random elements to return. Change it to a 1.

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($array, 1);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

This code is tested and works:

```
$myArray = array("test 1", "test2");

gettitles($myArray);

function gettitles ($array){
    $rand_keys = array_rand($array, 1);
    echo $array[$rand_keys] . "\n";
}
```

The function you're choosing to use **array_rand** returns the key to the random elements, not the content of the element itself.

Comment: in this way it says undefined index

Comment: if i echo  then echo $rand_keys it gives random index of array 0 or 1 not its value

Comment: It returns the element key. From there you have to pull the data using the key. I"ll edit my answer to show.

Comment: its giving random text with error undefined index.text 1 or some times undefined index:text 2

Comment: Code I just edited in I actually typed in and verified. If you're passing a valid array in, it will randomly echo the contents of a single element.

Comment: I print array which i am passing it is as     `Array ( [0] => text 1 [1] => text 2 ) `

Answer (score 1):

[array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) function
picks one or more random entries out of an array, and returns the key (or keys) of the random entries. It uses a pseudo random number generator that is not suitable for cryptographic purposes.
So, instead of 2 pass 1.

```
function gettitles ($array){
  shuffle($array);
  $rand_keys= array_values($array);
  echo $array[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
  echo $array[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
}
```

It will work.

EDIT

And use combo of [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function with [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) it will work.

```
function gettitles ($array){
  shuffle($array);
  $rand_keys= array_values($array);
  echo $array[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
  echo $array[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
function gettitles ($array){
  shuffle($array);
  $rand_keys= array_values($array);
  echo $rand_keys[0] . "\n";
  echo $rand_keys[1] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: in this way it says undefined index,.
if i echo then echo $rand_keys it gives random index of array 0 or 1 not its value

Comment: its giving random text with error undefined index.text 1 or some times undefined index:text 2

Comment: Check EDIT 2 portion, thats final working, I just checked that